# Use an iframe of a localhost app

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, iframe

I have a page of my rails app that I would like to use as an iframe on different webpage. The part of my rails app is the `new` view for my `score` object. At the moment my rails app is just locally hosted. To test my iframe, I have an HTML page in my `public` folder of my rails app.

Here is the `test.html` page

```
<html>

<iframe width="400" height="400" src="scores/new?site_id=191">

</iframe>

</html>
```

This isn't working, though. Here is the error I get when I inspect the iframe

`GET file:///Users/spencerhanson/Documents/Projects/net-promoter-score/public/scores/new?site_id=191 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

I know public/scores/new/.. isn't a place that exists in my project. I can't figure why it's trying to look there. The `test.html` file is in the `/public/` directory. The thing here is, I had this working before, with the same `src` tag in my iframe. I haven't changed anything, and then one day the iframe just stopped working on my test page. I can't figure out what's going wrong. I know it's probably the `src` tag of my iframe, since I'm trying to display a site hosted locally on a page that is also local

Comment: Well, it's looking in public/scores/new since you declared that in your src tag.

Comment: Yes, but this was working before. I've tried many different `src` tags but I can't find one that works. I think the fact that it's local is making it tougher

Comment: If you opened "test.html" in your browser, it won't work. Make sure you have started the rails web server and are viewing the page at a url that looks something like "http://localhost:3000/test.html" and not a URL like "file:///Users/spencerhanson/Documents/Projects/net-promoter-score/public/test.html".

Answer (score 5):

I figure out that opening the html file as [localhost:3000/test.html](http://localhost:3000/test.html) was the answer, thanks to [@absurdhero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290621/absurdhero)

Answer (score 3):

I tried sending full path like:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/myfolder/photos-iframe.php?id=2"
  name="thumbnails"
  frameborder="0"
  style="width: 100%;
  height: 150px;">
```

and its worked for me.